# How to get random similar integers of the format like input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

let's say I have an decimal number like `20.65`. I want to get x random decimal number that follows:

1. Should have same number of digits.
2. Should have same number of decimal places.
3. Should be negative if the input integer is.
4. There should be no repetition of any outputs or same as the input.

**Example**

I gave an input like:

```py
Enter number : 50.26
Enter no of random numbers to be generated : 5
```

then it's output should be like:

```
12.36
69.74
58.39
54.56
94.45
```

**Example 2:**

Input:

```py
Enter number : 5650.265
Enter no of random numbers to be generated : 5
```

then it's output should be like:

```
1652.326
6925.743
5844.394
5464.562
9448.454
```

**Example 3:**

Input:

```py
Enter number : -456
Enter no of random numbers to be generated : 5
```

then it's output should be like:

```
-566
-492
-452
-151
-944
```

**What I have tried :**

```py
from random import randint

n = float(input("Enter number : "))
x = int(input("Enter no of random integers to be generated : "))

min_choice = int('1'+''.join('0' for i in range(len(str(n))-1)))
max_choice = int(''.join('9' for i in range(len(str(n)))))

for i in range(x):
    print(randint(min_choice, max_choice))
```

which outputs as:

```
Enter number : 53.25
Enter no of random integers to be generated : 5
44864
29942
25832
20500
68083
```

So, as I can't the decimal places where I am struck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split it into two functions, one to generate a single number, and the other to collect the values making sure no duplicates are included:

```
import random

def gen_num(inp): 
    out = "" 
    if inp[0] == '-':
        out += "-"
        inp = inp[1:]      # Skip sign

    # The loop insures the generated numbers 
    # are of the same length as inp
    for dig in inp: 
        if dig == ".":     # Keeping decimal separator where it was 
            out += "." 
        else: 
            out += str(random.randint(1, 9)) 
    return out 

def gen_nums(inp, n): 
    out = set()            # Sets can't contain duplicates
    while len(out) < n: 
        num = gen_num(inp)
        if num != inp:     # Making sure no output number is same as input
            out.add(num) 
    return out 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp = input("Enter number: ")
    n = int(input("Enter no of random numbers to be generated: "))
    for v in gen_nums(inp, n):
        print(v)
```

Beware of casting the input to a float and back, you might be subject to floating point error.
Also be aware that there is a finite number of numbers that can be generated given the constraints (you can't generate `9` values from input `1`) and you might want to define what should happen in such case (what do you think would happen using the code above?).

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the input to a str and then use split

```
user_input = 123.321
input_parts = str(user_input).split('.') # This will return a list ["123", "321"]
```

Then you could get the lengths of each with len

```
left_side = len(input_parts[0])
right_side = len(input_parts[1])
```

Use those lenghts to generate appropriate length integers and join them.

```
left_num = str(random.randint(10**(left_side - 1),(10**left_side)-1)) 
right_num = str(random.randint(10**(right_side - 1),(10**right_side)-1))
```

Now you have 2 numbers of appropriate length. Just join them.

```
sides = [left_num, right_num]
merge = '.'.join(sides)
final_num = float(merge)
```

Comment: Add an if/else for if it's less than 0 and add a - to the string accordingly.